# SQL SELF JOIN return null if not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently, I got a table `A` like this:

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| VoucherID| AccountID | TransactionID |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 48       | 96        | 10            |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 48       | 14        | 10            |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 37       | 14        | 88            |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 37       | 25        | 88            |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 57       | 12        | 30            |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
|.......
```

I try to SELF JOIN this table by

```
SELECT account_log.*, reciprocal_account.AccountID as Reciprocal_accountID
FROM A AS account_log
LEFT JOIN A AS reciprocal_account ON account_log.VoucherID = reciprocal_account.VoucherID
WHERE account_log.AccountID <> reciprocal_account.AccountID
```

I got this

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| VoucherID| AccountID | TransactionID | Reciprocal_accountID |
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 48       | 96        | 10            | 14                   |
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 37       | 14        | 88            | 25                   |
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
```

What I expect is when VoucherID doesn't have any reciprocal account, that record will return null, like this

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| VoucherID| AccountID | TransactionID | Reciprocal_accountID |
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 48       | 96        | 10            | 14                   |
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 37       | 14        | 88            | 25                   |
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
| 57       | 12        | 30            | null                 |
+----------+-----------+---------------+----------------------+
```

Is there any elegant approach? Thanks all.

Comment: That's not the result thrown by the published query.

Comment: Provide source table as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: In the absence of any columns to order by it's not possible to identify which is the account and which is the reciprocal account - does the table have any such column , such as an auto_increment primary key or datestamp?

Comment: Yes, the table has an auto_increment PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use aggregation?

```
select transaction_id, voucher_id,
       min(account_id) as account_id,
       nullif(max(account_id), min(account_id)) as reciprocal_account_id
from a
group by transaction_id, voucher_id;
```

You could also do this using `left join`:

```
SELECT account_log.*, reciprocal_account.AccountID as Reciprocal_accountID
FROM A account_log LEFT JOIN
     A reciprocal_account
     ON account_log.VoucherID = reciprocal_account.VoucherID AND
        account_log.AccountID < reciprocal_account.AccountID;
```

Answer (score 1):

By including `account_log.AccountID <> reciprocal_account.AccountID` in your where clause, you are effectively changing the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN, since `<>` will always be false if one argument is NULL.  Add that condition to the ON clause instead, or use null-safe equals with a NOT: `NOT(account_log.AccountID <=> reciprocal_account.AccountID)`

Answer (score 1):

If there are only ever a maximum of 2 transactions per voucher and you have an auto_increment id then you can use rownumber (if on version 8 or above) or correlated sub queries (any version)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
CREATE TABLE t
(id int auto_increment primary key,VoucherID INT, AccountID INT, TransactionID INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(null, 48       , 96        , 10            ),
(null, 48       , 14        , 10            ),
(null, 37       , 14        , 88            ),
(null, 37       , 25        , 88            ),
(null, 57       , 12        , 30            );

select a.voucherid,a.accountid,a.transactionid,b.accountid
from
(
SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by voucherid order by id) rn
FROM t AS account_log
) a
left join
(SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by voucherid order by id) rn
FROM t AS account_log) b
on a.voucherid = b.voucherid and b.rn = a.rn+1 
where a.rn = 1;

select t.voucherid,t.accountid,t.transactionid,
        (Select accountid 
        from t t1 
        where t1.voucherid = t.voucherid and
                t1.id > t.id
        order by t1.id desc limit 1) raccount 
from  t
where id = (select min(id) from t t1 where t1.voucherid = t.voucherid)
;
```

Note the test to select the earliest id for the result

Both queries give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I might oversee something, but why not simply selecting the null entries as well at the left join?

```
SELECT account_log.*, reciprocal_account.AccountID as Reciprocal_accountID
FROM A AS account_log
LEFT JOIN A AS reciprocal_account ON account_log.VoucherID = reciprocal_account.VoucherID
WHERE account_log.AccountID <> reciprocal_account.AccountID OR reciprocal_account.AccountID is null
```